# Unable to use server command from client using unity mirror

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, unity-networking, unity3d-mirror

Im trying to make a smart usable object system.
When the player is getting close to one of the usable items he will be able to press a button and use this specific item. everything works except for the use command execution;

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using Mirror;

public class Usable : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public void Use(GameObject[] allUsables, Player CurrentClient, GameObject[] vents = null)
    {
        if (CurrentClient.isLocalPlayer)
        {
            //this.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().AssignClientAuthority(CurrentClient.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().connectionToClient);
            switch (this.name)
            {
                case string name when name.Contains("EmergencyButton"):
                    Debug.Log("Reached Log Point");
                    CmdEmergencyButton();
                    break;
                default:
                    Debug.LogError("Not possible!");
                    break;
            }
            //this.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().RemoveClientAuthority();
        }
    }

    [Command]
    private void CmdEmergencyButton()
    {
        RpcEmergency();
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    private void RpcEmergency()
    {
        //Activates emergency button effect
        GameObject.Find("EmergencyButton").transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

And calling the use function like this:

```cs
[Client]
void ActivateUse()
{
    if(isLocalPlayer)
    {
        Debug.Log("Client using");
        //currUsables has all the nearby usable objects
        GameObject currentToUse = GameObject.Find(currUsables[0].name);
        //Using that object.
        currentToUse.GetComponent<Usable>().Use(allUsables, this, allVents);
    }
}
```

From player object.
When calling CmdEmergencyButton() nothing happens except for this warning in the console;
[Click to see warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwQ38.jpg)

```
Trying to send command for object without authority. Usable.CmdEmergencyButton
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
```

I have tried giving authority to the client to use command from this object (comments in use function) but still nothing.
Any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: If you don't have the authority over the object because it is e.g. spawned by the server .. then all Cmd and Rpc calls have to be done on the player itself

Comment: Thanks! rookie mistake...